# TextView values continue to be null

Tags: android, dialog

I'm trying to use a dialog box to add values to a database. However, I cannot seem to get the values from the layout, as they always come null. Here is my code:

```
public class WlAddDialog extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(com.mutoor.autoreply.R.layout.whitelistadd, null));
    builder.setPositiveButton(com.mutoor.autoreply.R.string.add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.d("Dialog", "Starting dialog");
            Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            Log.d("Dialog", "Context Received");
            WlHelper wl = new WlHelper(c);
            Log.d("Dialog", "Created Whitelist Helper");
            TextView eName = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.entryName);
            TextView eNumber = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.entryNumber);
            Log.d("Dialog", "Name = " + eName.getText().toString() + " , Number = " + eNumber.getText().toString());
            wl.createEntry(eName.getText().toString(), eNumber.getText().toString());
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(com.mutoor.autoreply.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

}
And here is my output:

```
01-02 22:23:23.350: D/Dialog(26471): Starting dialog
01-02 22:23:23.350: D/Dialog(26471): Context Received
01-02 22:23:23.358: D/Dialog(26471): Created Whitelist Helper
01-02 22:23:23.358: D/AndroidRuntime(26471): Shutting down VM
01-02 22:23:23.358: E/AndroidRuntime(26471): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 22:12:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(25973): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 22:23:23.358: E/AndroidRuntime(26471): at com.mutoor.autoreply.WlAddDialog$1.onClick(WlAddDialog.java:36)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That is inside some onClick check that.

Comment: @BigFerdes Post your full activity code.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
TextView eName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.entryName);
TextView eNumber = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.entryNumber);
```

to get TextView values if you are using custom layout for Dialog

EDIT : change your code as:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

     View view = inflater.inflate(com.mutoor.autoreply.R.layout.whitelistadd, null);
    builder.setView(view);
            TextView eName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.entryName);
            TextView eNumber = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.entryNumber);

    builder.setPositiveButton(com.mutoor.autoreply.R.string.add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.d("Dialog", "Starting dialog");
            Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            Log.d("Dialog", "Context Received");
            WlHelper wl = new WlHelper(c);
            Log.d("Dialog", "Created Whitelist Helper");

            Log.d("Dialog", "Name = " + eName.getText().toString() + " , Number = " + eNumber.getText().toString());
            wl.createEntry(eName.getText().toString(), eNumber.getText().toString());
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am not able to call this function. The only way I could call findViewById was from an activity. This class extends DialogFragment so I'm not sure how to do so. I have also tried passing the TextViews directly as arguments in the constructor but that seems to fail as well.

Comment: @BigFerdes : k post some more code by which we can try to help you to access textView's inside onClick

Comment: Okay, I updated my question. I googled this error but all the solutions I tried have not worked.

Comment: @BigFerdes : you have these TextViews entryName and entryNumber inside whitelistadd layout ?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help, but I will think of restructuring my code and looking through Android Documentation for a solution.

Comment: @BigFerdes : your code is fine you just need place this code in proper place see this tutorial :http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Answer (score 1):

If both TextViews

```
TextView eName = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.entryName);
TextView eNumber = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.entryNumber);
```

are parts of Dialog layout, then they should be,

```
TextView eName = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.entryName);
TextView eNumber = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.entryNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking up the text boxes from your activity's layout instead of your dialog's layout. I'd expect that you search for the TextView's in the dialog and use the values provided there to accomplish your database transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You this way:

> TextView eName = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.entryName);
>   TextView eNumber = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.entryNumber);

You need to define the `layout.findViewById()` to access the views from your dialog layout only thats why you are getting nullpointer error. Try out i think this is the only issue.